# Can the new primary domain of a Google Apps account be previsously an alias of the old primary domain?

Tags: google-admin-sdk

We are about to change our Google Apps account primary domain, for a consistent branding since our old primary domain isn't the one of our company.

We read the official Google Apps Admin SDK how-to here:
https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-customers#changing_a_customers_primary_domain_name

And we plan to use this script on GitHub:
https://github.com/marcelobern/Google-Admin-SDK-Domain

Nevertheless, our new domain is already an alias of the old primary domain on Google Apps, and not a separate domain on the same Google Apps account.

Will this work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the domain must be a secondary domain, not an alias. Delete the alias and re-add the domain as a secondary before attempting to change it to the primary domain.